# Getting error GTK when compiling although GTK is already Installed

Tags: linux, package-management, yum

I'm a linux newbie and trying to compile a software but getting an error;

**it is telling me that GTK is not installed**

```
checking for GTK... configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.0.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

**But here when i check, it says it is available**

```
yum info gtk2-2.18.9-6.el6.centos.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.cica.es
 * extras: ftp.cica.es
 * updates: centos.aol.in
Installed Packages
Name        : gtk2
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.18.9
Release     : 6.el6.centos
Size        : 12 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda-CentOS-201112091719.x86_64
Summary     : The GIMP ToolKit (GTK+), a library for creating GUIs for X
URL         : http://www.gtk.org
License     : LGPLv2+
```

Description : GTK+ is a multi-platform toolkit for creating graphical user
            : interfaces. Offering a complete set of widgets, GTK+ is suitable for
            : projects ranging from small one-off tools to complete application
            : suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gtk+ and gtk2 are totally different packages.  You need +

Comment: It seems a package name discrepancy is the cause of the problem.